# Can not select from two table: occurred while calling setter for property

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Im usig Spring mvc and Hibernate. When I select from 2 tables, I received an exception following as:

My Bean (Cars and Map):

Cars class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Cars")
public class Car implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5924361831551833717L;  

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Integer carId;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="map_id")
 private Map mapId;

 public Integer getCarId() {
    return this.carId;
 }

 public void setCarId(Integer carId) {
    this.carId = carId;
 }

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Map getMapId() {
    return this.mapId;
}

public void setMapId(Map mapId) {
    this.mapId = mapId;
 }
}
```

Map class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Map")
public class Map implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5527566248002296042L;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Integer mapId;

 @Column(name = "address")
 private String address;

 public Integer getMapId() {
    return mapId;
 }

 public void setMapId(Integer mapId) {
    this.mapId = mapId;
 }

 public String getAddress() {
    return address;
 }

 public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  } 
 }
```

SQL (select from 2 tables):

```
SELECT  CAR.ID AS carId, 
    CAR.NAME AS name, 
    MAP.ID AS mapId
FROM    CARS CAR, 
    MAP MAP
WHERE   CAR.MAP_ID = MAP.ID
```

Log message:

```
BasicPropertyAccessor - HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.totoroads.web.model.Car, setter method of property: mapId
BasicPropertyAccessor - HHH000091: Expected type: com.totoroads.web.model.Map, actual value: java.lang.Integer
CarRepositoryImpl - error at CarRepositoryImpl.getAllCars: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [com.tct.web.model.Car.mapId (expected type = com.tct.web.model.Map)]; target = [com.tct.web.model.Car@23743c55], property value = [13] setter of com.tct.web.model.Car.mapId
```

How to fix this error, thank so much !

Comment: can you share Map bean ?

Comment: hi @santoshgore: I have posted Map bean

Comment: you are trying to get AllCars from Map bean , so you have to declare List of cars in Map bean .use bidirectional Many to one mapping.

Comment: I think you should use Address as a embedded entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Map")
public class Map implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5527566248002296042L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer mapId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mapId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Car> cars;

  @Column(name = "address")
  private String address;

  public Integer getMapId() {
     return mapId;
  }

  public void setMapId(Integer mapId) {
     this.mapId = mapId;
  }

  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  } 
  public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
  }

  public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
      this.cars= cars;
  }
}
```

use above map class

Comment: I have tried as your recommend, but it still same error

Comment: add cascade = CascadeType.ALL in car bean.

Comment: hI @santosh gore: this issue has fixed when i use method: return (List<Car>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Car.class).list(); Thank you so much :)